# Не выводиться noavatar в laravel

Tags: phpmyadmin

Подскажите почему не выводится аватар с папки Storage. Я понимаю, что скорее всего не правильно указан url до папки, есть в этом проблема до подскажите как правильно указать url[image: Выводиться вот такое отображение]

```
<div class="testimonial__about">
  <div class="avatar v_middle">
  <img src="<?php echo e(Storage::url($r->user->avatar)); ?>" alt="No avatar">
</div>
```

Comment: Скорее всего, что нету файла там, куда указывает `src`. Для лучшего понимая проблемы нужно лучше её описать.`(хотя бы указать значение $r->user->avatar и в какой папке он должен быть)`

Comment: @Владислав Я не сильно понимаю в php мне помогали создать сайт, на данный момент где у меня находиться avatar это названия сайта/public/storage и само названия картинки noavatar.png

Comment: Что выводит в консоль, какой путь у картинки, значение `$r->user->avatar`? Возможно нету картинки, возможно `Storage::disk('public')->url($r->user->avatar)`, возможно 'public/storage' - если Laravel, то проверить ссылку или заново создать `php artisan storage:link` (как удалять не помню, вроде `unlink`), возможно фасад использует диск по умолчанию. Вариантов много, сложно помочь если ты не дашь больше информации. С твоей проблемой только наугад.

Comment: @Владислав Скажите какую нужно дать информацию, попробую предоставить.

Comment: @Владислав если смотреть через панель разработчика то путь там такой: src="/storage/avatars/hNUhK9v4vLOMMXJ5yUxTf2yc7TAaKa3EMxr9JXKp.jpeg" но я не знаю от куда взялся такой url к картинке

Comment: Проверь, есть ли там действительно файл (перейди в папке с проектом, дальше `public/storage/avatars/`)? `p.s.` url к картинке правильный.

Comment: @Владислав нет, но там есть картинка под названием avatar.png

Comment: @Владислав Все разобрался, спасибо за новодки)

Comment: И в чём была проблема?

Comment: @Владислав создал папку avatars, там переименовал картинку в название hNUhK9v4vLOMMXJ5yUxTf2yc7TAaKa3EMxr9JXKp.jpeg и все заработало